# Treating a textarea as an input field?

Tags: html, css, forms, css-transforms

I'm building a contact form with a `css transform` effect that uses the labels on the input fields. I need the final one's label to act the same way as the previous ones, but this final one needs to be a multi-line text area. Is there anyway to accomplish this?

**HTML**

```
<div class="questions">
            <div class='form-field'>
            <input required='required'>
            <label>
            Hey, what's your name?
            </label>
            </div>

            <div class='form-field'>
            <input required='required'>
            <label>
            How about your email?
            </label>
            </div>

            <div class='form-field'>
            <input textarea required='required' rows="5" cols="30">
            <label>
            Finally, what's your message?
            </label>
            </textarea>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /questions -->
```

**CSS**

```
body .form-field {
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100px;
  right: 0;
  font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
  max-width: 500px;
  width: 92%;
  margin:40px 0;
}

body label {
  font-size: 23px;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  width: 400px;
  color: white;
  top: 28px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-property: transform;
}
body input, body textarea {
border: none;
padding: 40px 0px 20px 0px;
box-shadow: 0px 3px white, 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
color: white;
text-shadow: 0px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
background: transparent;
outline: none;
height: 19px;
font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
transition-property: transform;
font-size: 17px;
max-width: 500px;
width: 92%;
}

body input:focus + label, body textarea:focus + label {
  transform: translateY(-39px) translateX(-80px) scale(0.6);
}

body label:after {
content: "";
box-shadow: inset 8px -8px 0 white, -3px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: -100px;
height: 28px;
transition-duration: 0.1s;
transition-property: transform;
transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(0.6);
width: 60px;
float: right;
display: block;
margin: 13px auto;
}
body input:valid + label, body textarea:valid + label{
  transform: translateY(-39px) translateX(-80px) scale(0.6);
}
body input:valid + label:after, body textarea:valid + label:after {
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(260px) rotate(-45deg);
}
body input:invalid + label::after, body textarea:invalid + label::after {
transform: translateX(260px) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z0wt3ahk/1/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how you make an textarea. Try this:

Working example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z0wt3ahk/4/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="questions">
            <div class='form-field'>
            <input required='required'>
            <label>
            Hey, what's your name?
            </label>
            </div>

            <div class='form-field'>
            <input required='required'>
            <label>
            How about your email?
            </label>
            </div>

            <div class='form-field'>
            <textarea required='required' rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
            <label>
            Finally, what's your message?
            </label>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /questions -->
```

Comment: Y'know, I had that, except I only closed it after `</label>`. This works great, thanks for the help!

Comment: Nah, you had `<input textarea...>`. Missed the closing `</textarea>` though! Hehe

Comment: I've been trying this for a half hour, believe me I've had other options lol This is just what it landed on when I posted xD

Comment: Okey, seemed to work OK after I changed it to an actual `<textarea>` or am I missing what you want to happen? EDIT: Sorry, didn't see that you had accepted the answer, never mind! PS. We all get stuck on small stupid thing sometimes ;)

Comment: Yeah, I just couldn't figure it out for the life of me, sometimes just need another set of eyes on it.

Comment: True that, true that!